# Howto use gcloud to create cloud launcher products clusters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-launcher

I'm new to google cloud and i try to experiment it.
I can see that preparing scripts is some kind of vital if i want to create and delete clusters every days.
For dataproc clusters, it's easy :

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create spark-6-m \
     --async \
     --project=my-project-id \
     --region=us-east1 \
     --zone=us-east1-b \
     --bucket=my-project-bucket \
     --image-version=1.2 \
     --num-masters=1 \
     --master-boot-disk-size=10GB \
     --master-machine-type=n1-standard-1 \
     --worker-boot-disk-size=10GB \
     --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-1 \
     --num-workers=6 \
     --initialization-actions=gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter2/jupyter2.sh
```

Now, i'd like to create a cassandra cluster. I see that the code launcher allows to do that easily too but I can't find a gcloud command to automate it.

Is there a way to create cloud launcher products clusters via gcloud ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Launcher deployments can be replicated from the Cloud Shell using Custom Deployments [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/docs/custom-deployments).

Once the Cloud Launcher deployment (in this case a Cassandra cluster) is finished the details of the deployment can be seen in the Deployment Manager [[2]](https://console.cloud.google.com/deployments?_ga=2.186857064.-1719188528.1528705041). 
The deployment details have an Overview section with the configuration and the imported files used for the deployment process. Download the “Expanded Config” file, this will be the .yaml file for the custom deployment [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/create-a-configuration). Download the imports files to the same directory as the .yaml file to be able to deploy correctly [[4]](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/deploy-your-resources).

This files and configuration will create an equivalent deployment as the Cloud Launcher.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at the docs you link and try this. It seems to be a little more complicated than the simple command used for dataproc. Maybe will I try to install Cassandra on the spark cluster (made with dataproc)...